# Ubuntu error when installing Python packages

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
pip3 isntall netmiko
#downloads all requirements (into cashe) but gives this error.
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyasn1-0.4.7.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I tried using `sudo pip3 install netmiko`,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 109, in apport_excepthook
    pr.add_proc_info(extraenv=['PYTHONPATH', 'PYTHONHOME'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 543, in add_proc_info
    self.add_proc_environ(pid, extraenv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 610, in add_proc_environ
    env = _read_file('environ', dir_fd=proc_pid_fd).replace('\n', '\\n')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 73, in _read_file
    with open(path, 'rb', opener=lambda path, mode: os.open(path, mode, dir_fd=dir_fd)) as fd:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    with open(path, 'rb', opener=lambda path, mode: os.open(path, mode, dir_fd=dir_fd)) as fd:
TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not list

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

the only way it works is by

```
sudo apt-get update

pip3 install netmiko --user
```

then I have to reboot (from terminal) to get it working.
This happened to every module I installed,is there a fix to this?

I am running the default python 3.6.8 (preinstalled on Ubuntu 18)

Comment: `python3 -m pip install --user "packagename"`

Comment: Why not create a virtual environment and try ?!

Comment: @error404 well this works without rebooting so I guess it is an answer,but is there a smaller to fix to make my downloads easier just "pip3 install package"

Comment: seems to me that your pip is broken. can you try after re-installing the same...`apt-get install python3-pip`